# Running a single test method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, ocunit

Using OCUnit & Xcode, is there a way of running just one test?

Ideally, I'd be able to run just one test method, but if there's a way to just run a single test case, that would be OK too.

What I'm currently doing is running the 'Test' task which runs all of my tests, but this takes up a lot of time, which ideally could be spent doing other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post from an Xcode engineer:

http://chanson.livejournal.com/119578.html

The last paragraph explains how to specify a single test case class.

For more info see Chris' entire series on unit testing:

http://chanson.livejournal.com/tag/unit%20testing